# Отображение файла php

Tags: php

Начал изучать php, загрузил денвер с php себе на комп, создал папку с назвньем сайта, а в этой папке создал первую страницу, index.php.

Запустил сайт, всё отображается нормально, но когда я жму на сам файл index.php, у меня отображается код в открываемом окне браузера, это нормально?

Comment: где вы на него жмете?

Comment: в папке, просто запускаю файл

Comment: он у меня ещё почему-та открывается с помощью оперы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно. Вы открываете **текстовый файл** `index.php` через браузер, поэтому и показывается исходный код.